# Node.js Parse huge CSV & find specific row of data by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, npm

Does anyone know a npm package that would be best suited to iterate over a csv file and be able to find a value and append/update to that row?

I currently have no code to show as i am testing packages, i have been looking at D3

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

> Brace yourself.

1. Get all the CSV data in String format in a local variable
2. localVariable.split('/n');---> This is going to create an array of CSV rows.
3. loop through the CSV rows. Each row will get you an object.
4. Now Each object you got is an string, convert them to array also using split.
5. Now use the filter function to sort it out.

If you didn't get it. Share your git project link I'll fork and write the code for you.

Comment: Would this be quick enough, my data is 150k rows and 8 columns. i have used "csv-parse" to get my rows but even loading them it takes a good 10 seconds. then i need to shift through them all (they are objects currently). i dont really have code for the node side of things:

https://pastebin.com/h3NGPpn8

Comment: Mind sharing the sample data? And, do you have a repo for this code? @MetalSlugSnk

Comment: Or, may be try this. https://github.com/klaemo/csv-stream @MetalSlugSnk

Comment: I do not have a repo for this, i am just working on my local machine. This is some sample data. i am trying to match the ID's then change the eq_site_limit hu_site_limit fields. thanks for all your help
https://pastebin.com/LF2bnNnr

also with the code i shared first, it gets all the rows

Comment: git repository. @MetalSlugSnk